# Error when using Side Input - withSideInputs method not accepting KV type as input

Tags: apache-beam

I am facing the following error when I use sideinputs.

With the following model code:

```
PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> view1= information
                .apply(View.<String, String>asMap());

PCollection<KV<String, Position>> FileData;

FileData.apply("populate",
ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Position>, KV<String, Position>>() {
                    @ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

}.withSideInputs(view1));
```

The error occurs when withSideInputs method is called. The withsideinput is not accepting KV type value as input . Could you please tell what I am missing.

Error Message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SideInputHandler.addSideInputValue(SideInputHandler.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.apex.translation.operators.ApexParDoOperator$2.process(ApexParDoOperator.java:225)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.apex.translation.operators.ApexParDoOperator$2.process(ApexParDoOperator.java:207)
        at com.datatorrent.api.DefaultInputPort.put(DefaultInputPort.java:79)
        at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.AbstractReservoir$SpscArrayBlockingQueueReservoir.sweep(AbstractReservoir.java:413)
        at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.GenericNode.run(GenericNode.java:269)
        at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer$2.run(StreamingContainer.java:1428)
```

Sample Code to reproduce the issue:

```
public void testMapAsEntrySetSideInput() {

    final PCollectionView<Map<String, Integer>> view =
        pipeline.apply("CreateSideInput", Create.of(KV.of("a", 1), KV.of("b", 3)))
            .apply(View.<String, Integer>asMap());

    PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> output =
        pipeline.apply("CreateMainInput", Create.of(2 /* size */))
            .apply(
                "OutputSideInputs",
                ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, KV<String, Integer>>() {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    assertEquals((int) c.element(), c.sideInput(view).size());
                    assertEquals((int) c.element(), c.sideInput(view).entrySet().size());
                    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : c.sideInput(view).entrySet()) {
                      c.output(KV.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                    }
                  }
                }).withSideInputs(view));

    PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(
        KV.of("a", 1), KV.of("b", 3));

    pipeline.run();
  }
```

Comment: It seems that you're using the Apex runner. Does this happen with other runners, eg with the direct runner?

Comment: I used Spark runner and Apex runner and facing the same error.

Comment: Does it happen in the Direct runner? And, this definitely sounds like a bug in these runners - could you try to provide a minimal code example that we can use to reproduce and fix this?

Comment: I have added a sample code to reproduce the issue. I am still getting experience in this framework to provide a solid working sample code. Please look into this issue as our implementation design is changing to use JOIN SDK because of this. This is a important functionality which should work in all runners.

Comment: I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3130 for Apex runner. I confirmed that the issue does *not* affect direct runner (nor, AFAIK, Dataflow runner); and I was unable to reproduce it with the Spark runner. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the implementation of the Apex runner; it is maintained by the Apache Beam community and lead by Thomas Weise - I hope he or someone else pick it up.

Comment: Could you please also file a issue for Spark runner.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Apex runner and it has been resolved for Beam release 2.3.0.